# Play Store can download but not install apps; getting error code 927

Tags: google-play-store, updates, installation, google-pixel

On my Pixel phone, apps will download on Play Store, but once the download completes, it doesn't install. After some time, there's a notification from the Play Store that says

[image: not responding]

> Google Play isn't responding. Try again in a few minutes, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting. (Error code: 927)

Usually, if I restart the phone, the apps can be installed, but if I wait a few hours, I have to repeat the process.

Does anyone know of a way to fix the issue permanently?

Comment: Instead of restarting phone restart playstore app.

Comment: I have already that and that, and it doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Did you interfere with playstore apk in your phone like rooting, custom rom and other stuff ? Can you tell what message you are getting when apps does not install ?

Comment: I have not rooted the phone or added any mods. Eventually I get a notification that says **Google play isn't responding**

Comment: try to update google play app

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue on 7.1. What seemed to help was: going to the Play Store app info, force stop, clear data, force stop, open back up. All updates went through, and even though there is still a delay after the download and before the start of the installation, it's significantly improved at about 10-15s as opposed to minutes or never happening. I'll probably try to clear data for other related services to see if it helps any further.

Comment: It started working for me. Somewhere I read that uninstalling the updates for the play store app then re-installing the updates can fix the issue. I tried that, and it seems to improve it in the same way as you mentioned and has been good for awhile now. I did try doing what you said, but after awhile it just starts doing it again.

Comment: I ended up clearing the data of all google play services and google/google+ and it seems to be back to normal after reboot, installs start right after download. Time will tell if this will persist but so far so good.

Answer (score -2):

Now you do not have to worry about losing any apps or games you like because there is an app called APK Extractor that helps change the app from Play Store to apk. With this application we can make back up instalan to raw apk file which then we can save or we share to other friends. Here are the steps:

1. Download the APK Extractor app directly from the Google Play store, this app is available for free.
2. Once installed, run APK extractor then a list of applications will appear installed on your phone.
3. Select which application we will back up or change to apk file.
4. If you select more than one application, tap the application app for a bit longer.
5. Then select the Extract menu, then immediately extraction process will run.
6. Once completed, Apk files will be stored in the ExtractedApks folder which is automatically stored in the internal memory.
7. You can see apk list and then can move it on PC or share it to friends.

That's how to change apps from the play store to apk, as extracted app notes are just freeware or free, because for premium apps there is usually a protector that blocks APK Extractor action.

Comment: This won't fix the problem of the Play Store not installing the apps in the first place, though.